# Url.Action puts an &amp; in my url, how can I solve this?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, url.action

I want to send the variables itemId and entityModel to the ActionResult CreateNote:

```
public ActionResult CreateNote(
        [ModelBinder(typeof(Models.JsonModelBinder))]
        NoteModel Model, string cmd, long? itemId, string modelEntity)
```

with this javascript:

```
Model.meta.PostAction = Url.Action("CreateNote", new { cmd = "Save", itemId = itemId, modelEntity = modelEntity});
```

However, the url being send is

```
localhost:1304/Administration/blue/en-gb/Entity/CreateNote?modelEntity=Phrase&amp;itemId=44
```

I want to send

```
localhost:1304/Administration/blue/en-gb/Entity/CreateNote?modelEntity=Phrase&itemId=44
```

How can I prevent Url.Action to put the & in front of the second variable that I want to send?

Comment: What makes you think that `&amp;` is not OK?

Comment: Because when I look at the ActionResult with a breakpoint, when I have localhost:1304/Administration/blue/en-gb/Entity/CreateNote?modelEntity=Phrase&amp;itemId=44 modelEntity = Phrase and itemId = null. When I turn them around in javascript and get localhost:1304/Administration/blue/en-gb/Entity/CreateNote?itemId=44&amp;modelEntity=Phrase itemId = 44 and modelEntity = null. That's why I think it has to do with the &amp;

Comment: @Oded — because the data is being inserted into JavaScript, not HTML.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

I didn't notice yesterday that you had `&amp;` I thought that was the SO editor had changed that. Try wrapping your `Url.Action()` in a `@Html.Raw()` to prevent the Encode of &.

Or alternatively only `Url.Action()` the controller/action bit and pass the two parameters as post data rather than directly on the url, jQuery should sort out the &'s for you that way.

Comment: This solution works, but why does Url.Action even get encoded? Talk about unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 14):

I think your problem is with `Model.meta.PostAction` - is that property a `string`?

If so then my guess would be that you're adding it to the page with either:

- Razor: `@Model.meta.PostAction`
- ASP view engine: `<%:Model.meta.PostAction%>`

Both of which automatically encode that string for you.

To fix it either use `@Html.Raw()`/`<%=` (both of which don't encode) or make the `PostAction` property an `IHtmlString` that knows that it's already been encoded:

```
string actionUrl = Url.Action("CreateNote", new { cmd = "Save", itemId = itemId, modelEntity = modelEntity});
Model.meta.PostAction = new HtmlString(actionUrl);
```