# Jquery submit adds flawed encoding

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

When I submit a form my browser goes to here:

```
Administration/Member/Navigate?personid=1771&amp;type=Information
```

When it should go here:

```
Administration/Member/Navigate?personid=1771&type=Information
```

The way I call the submit seems ordinary:

```
$("#user-form").submit();
```

Probably not related, but we've recently converted from aspx to razor. This has caused a lot of artifacts 'like this' to show up. It looks like the extra characters are coming from jQuery, though.

**Edit**:

I mistakenly thought the submit() call went right into the jQuery library (seemed to be the case when I was stepping through it), but there also seems to be this function:

```
    $("#user-form").submit(function () {
        var isValid = $("#user-form").valid();
        if (isValid)
        {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/UserManagement/ClassUser/Edit",
                data: $("#user-form").serialize(),
                success: function (id) { 
                    window.location.href = returnUrl; 
               },
                error: function(xhr, textStatus, error) {
                    showAlert("Error Saving User", xhr.responseText);
                }
            });

        }

        return false;
    });
```

Apparently the returnUrl variable had some extra encoding in it.

The answer appears to be here:

[Url.Action puts an &amp; in my url, how can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711521/url-action-puts-an-amp-in-my-url-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: Can you share the HTML form and the full JS code?

Comment: It might be some encoding going on, please share your code

Comment: You haven't shown how you generate that URL, without it this question can't be answered.

Comment: Those are not extra characters, razor encodes some characters. It is url encode of character '&'. Please share some code to understand better.

Comment: It's perfectly legit to [answer your own question you know?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking)